# Group Theory : What is $Ha \ne Hb$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

As a beginner of Group Theory, I got stuck with the following question:

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that whenever $Ha \ne Hb \space ,$ then  $aH \ne bH$. $(a,b \in G)$ Prove that $gHg^{-1} \subset H \space\space\forall g\in G$.

My **first** doubt is *what is exactly implied by* $Ha \ne Hb$ *in the above question? Does it mean*
$$ whenever \space ha\ne hb , ah\ne bh \space \forall\space h\in H $$ $$OR$$ $$whenever \space h_1a\ne h_2b , ah_1\ne bh_2 \space \forall \space h_1,h_2 \in H \space ?$$

I dont know whether this is a very silly doubt or not ; please help me clarify.

**Secondly** , it will be very helpful if you give me a hint how to proceed with this problem. Thank you in advance..

If this question is a repetition please give a link , but do not down-vote. I am very low in reputation.

Comment: It just means that as sets, $Ha$ is not the same set as $Hb$.

Comment: To make @user's comment a little more explicit: $Ha = \{ha:h\in H\}$ and so $Ha\neq Hb$ means that the *sets* $Ha$ and $Hb$ have different elements.

Comment: I have slightly edited my question to make my **FIRST** doubt more clear.. @Cameron Williams

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your **first** question has  been answered,

Now *Hints* to the **second** one:

> $Ha\neq Hb\implies aH\neq bH$ means $aH=bH\implies Ha=Hb$ means $b^{-1}a\in H\implies ab^{-1}\in H$.

Now let $g\in G,h\in H;h(g^{-1}g)=he\in H\implies (hg^{-1})g\in H\implies ghg^{-1}\in H$
which holds $\forall h,g$.

Thus $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$

Comment: @ learnmore :  You said $(g(g^{-1}H))=H\implies (g^{-1}H)g=H$. I think this is done assuming the fact that $aH=bH \implies Ha=Hb$. Here your $b$ is $e$ and your $a$ is $g$. However if it is so ,then you are replacing $H$ by $(g^{-1}H)$, but $g^{-1}$ may not belong to $H$. Again, help me if I am wrong..

Comment: @Qwerty;I have edited my answer to make things simpler for you;Now I think it must be easier for you.

Comment: That was wonderful.!! @learnmore